# Disable Vue Bootstrap Table Header Renaming

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using b-table on vue-bootstrap using this code:

```
b-table :fields="queryResult.columns" :items="queryResult.rows"
```

The field is like this: id, column_name, column_hide

But, it automatically generates 'translated' header name, column_name to Column Name.

Is there any way to disable 'auto-renaming' on that table header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [documents](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#field-definition-reference), there is a `label` attribute that can be set on the `fields` prop

> Appears in the columns table header (and footer if foot-clone is set).
>   Defaults to the field's key (in humanized format) if not provided.
>   It's possible to use empty labels by assigning an empty string "" but
>   be sure you also set headerTitle to provide non-sighted users a hint
>   about the column contents.